# Which approach is faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

Consider the following classes:

```
class SpeedAPI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 1

    def execute_method(self):
        return True
```

and

```
from speed_api import SpeedAPI

class MyAPI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 1

    def my_execute_method(self):
        SpeedAPI().execute_method()
```

I want to test the speed of execution for each method in each class. I have designed the following test to do so:

```
from speed_api import SpeedAPI
from myapi import MyAPI
import time
import threading

def test_speed_for_SpeedAPI():
    time_trials_SpeedAPI = 0
    for i in range(10000):
        start_time = time.time()
        SpeedAPI().execute_method()
        end_time = time.time()
        calculated_time = (end_time - start_time)
        time_trials_SpeedAPI += calculated_time
    averaged_time = (time_trials_SpeedAPI / 10000)
    print(averaged_time)

def test_speed_for_MyAPI():
    time_trials_MyAPI = 0
    for i in range(10000):
        start_time = time.time()
        MyAPI().my_execute_method()
        end_time = time.time()
        calculated_time = (end_time - start_time)
        time_trials_MyAPI += calculated_time
    averaged_time = (time_trials_MyAPI / 10000)
    print(averaged_time)

threads = [threading.Thread(target=test_speed_for_SpeedAPI), threading.Thread(target=test_speed_for_MyAPI)]

print('Testing speed for SpeedAPI')
threads[0].start()
threads[0].join()
print('Testing speed for MyAPI')
threads[1].start()
threads[1].join()
```

However, after running a few tests, I notice that there is inconsistency. Some times the `MyAPI` is faster than the `SpeedAPI`. Ultimately I *expect* the `SpeedAPI` to be faster. Am I wrong to expect this? I do realize the difference in execution time between the two is very minimal; However I am still interested in knowing which is faster and why.

Here are some sample test results:

```
Testing speed for SpeedAPI
5.976438522338867e-07
Testing speed for MyAPI
8.997201919555664e-07

Testing speed for SpeedAPI
4.0011405944824217e-07
Testing speed for MyAPI
8.000850677490234e-07

Testing speed for SpeedAPI
4.0068626403808596e-07
Testing speed for MyAPI
9.995698928833008e-07

Testing speed for SpeedAPI
5.038022994995118e-07
Testing speed for MyAPI
1.0046958923339845e-06
```

Where it is clear that the last trial shows an inconsistency. What could be the reasoning for this? Could it have to do with how fast I am running each test? I am running it manually, and spamming the terminal by executing the script, over and over again. Thanks to all of those who reply in advance.

Comment: A large part of the speed difference comes from the fact that, in the code you've given, `my_api` *literally just calls `speed_api`*. Function calls are a source of computational overhead that would account for the speed difference (which is consistently around 2x) - especially if the actual method is just `return True`, which is about as minimalist as a method can get. If your actual code is more complicated than this, please post it, because otherwise this is the straightforward answer

Comment: Consider using ``perf`` or ``timeit`` instead of your own setup! Note that ``MyAPI`` is never faster than ``SpeedAPI`` - ``1.0e-6`` is twice as large as ``5.0e-7``.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I really just want to know the difference in speed. My real code imports a method from an API, but I create my own instance method (similar to above) to call the function from the API. Honestly was just curious in the time it takes... With that being said, is it fair to say that (in this case) the `SpeedAPI` will always be the faster?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Well it's a good thing you noticed that... as I completely missed that... good catch.

Comment: This performance difference is probably completely irrelevant if your method actually does anything